# How to change the currency symbol for MONEY stereotype in OpenXava?

Tags: java, localization, openxava

I am having a problem with the currency at a particular site. The currency is displaying in $ although I have set the locale to South Africa. Excel and other programs reflect R. However my OpenXava application is reflecting $. I have tried several browsers and I am having the same problem. I have also set the language in Chrome and moved it to the top of my preferences.

Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

The Money editor uses the locale of the server to determine the currency symbol. So you have to change the locale of the server that executes the Tomcat. If it is not possible, you can start the Java that runs the Tomcat with these options:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

You should be able of adding these options editing catalina.sh/.bat and giving value to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. That is, in windows edit catalina.bat and add the next line at the beginning:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

Or if you're using Mac or Linux add the next line at the beginning of catalina.sh:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=ZA
```

In development, from OpenXava Studio or Eclipse, you can define the above options in the menu: Run > Run Configurations... > H= Arguments:

[image: Language options for Java in Eclipse]